# log4j - set different loglevel for different packages/classes

Tags: java, log4j

I use log4j for logging and i want to print all logger.debug statements in a particular class / selected package.

i set the cfg as below>

```
log4j.category.my.pkg=info
log4j.category.my.pkg.ab.class1=debug
```

but still only info messages are shown..

is this not the right way ?

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Instead of using 'category' use 'logger'. Hence, these level are configured for entire log4j, and does not depend on appender, etc.

Following change works:

```
log4j.logger.my.pkg=info
log4j.logger.my.pkg.ab.class1=debug
```

Comment: I know I'm late joining the party, but do you happen to have a link to the relevant page in the official docs explaining these settings, by any chance? :) I can see the value is in my `log4j.properties` in tomcat's `webapps/myProject/WEB-INF/classes/`folder, but I just don't get any `DEBUG` output in my IntelliJ console...

Comment: What is meant by "package"? Granted, the logger name is often a class name, but in reality, it is just a string with .'s in it. Will the logger look for properties with all possible prefixes, or just the whole string and everything before the last . ?

Answer (score 28):

Copying from my current log4j.properties:

```
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl=warn
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.sql=info
```

Comment: Not only was I looking up how to change the logger level for different packages, but those were actually the packages I was looking to change the logger level for!